# ajax function not opening a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i don't understand why ajax is not working.
my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function edit_row(id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            method:'get',
            url:'form.php',
            success:function(data)
            {
              $('#form_div').html(data);
            }
        });

    }
```

```
<?php
   echo '<td style='.$style.'>'.$status.'<a href="" title="Edit"  onClick=edit_row('.$data['type_id'].')><img src="images/pencil.png" width="30px" height="30px"></a></td></tr>';
?>
```

its not opening form.php onclick what is the problem please help me!!!

Comment: why would it open...its ajax

Comment: what u have in form.php the ajax just call the url. backend what u doing in form.php.??

Comment: You've not closed the Javascript, so the PHP is part of the script. Eh, you split the two piece of code now?

Comment: Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org) on that HTML.

Comment: One capability of jquery is that it can easily simplify your code so that you don't have to use onClick html attributes.

Comment: @Stefan — Standard DOM lets you do that just as easily.

Comment: @Quentin: My point is, since you're using jQuery already, why not ditch the onclick? jQuery facilitates unobtrusive event handling. It internally uses `addEventListener()` and `attachEvent()`.  Less markup, better separation of behaviour and content.

Comment: @Stefan — Same amount of markup. About the same amount of JS (if you don't include the overhead of loading jQuery) if you aren't supporting ancient IE and don't need attachEvent.

Comment: @Quentin: I am saying if you are using jQuery already then it makes sense to drop `onClick().` I'm not disputing you can also do that without using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put

```
href="javascript:void(0)"
```

instead of

```
href=""
```

else it will reload the page without calling the ajax

Answer (score 1):

You click the link. The JavaScript runs. The link is followed. A new page (with the same URL because you have `href=""`) loads. The JavaScript stops because its environment has gone away.

Use a button instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the 'id' to you form.php I guess you need to pass it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function edit_row(id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            method:'get',
            url:'form.php',
            data: {id: id },
            success:function(data)
            {
              $('#form_div').html(data);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (does not use `onClick` attribute):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a.edit').click(function(e) {    // or: $.on('click', 'a.edit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                method:'get',
                url: 'form.php',
                data: {id:id},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#form_div').html(data);
                }
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
    echo '<td style="$style">$status
          <a href="#" id="' . $data['type_id'] . '"  title="Edit" class="edit">
          <img src="images/pencil.png" width="30px" height="30px">
          </a></td></tr>';
?>
```